# Integration of multilayer perceptron

Tags: integration, regression, neural-networks

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function of $(m+n)$ inputs, i.e. $f(x_1, \cdots, x_m, y_1, \cdots, y_n) \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to compute a definite integral of $f$ over the first $m$ inputs:

$F(y_1, \cdots, y_n)=\int_{\alpha_1}^{\beta_1}\int_{\alpha_2}^{\beta_2}\cdots
\int_{\alpha_m}^{\beta_m}f(x_1, \cdots, x_m, y_1, \cdots, y_n)\,dx_m\,dx_{m-1}\cdots dx_1$,

where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ indicates a (predefined) real range.

Now, assume that there are no analytic solutions, neither for $f$ nor for $F$. But instead we have approximated $f$ with a multilayer perceptron (MLP), $M$.

The question: is there any algorithm that takes $M$ and returns another feedforward NN, $M^\prime$, that computes the function $F$? $\,\,\,$ In other words, can we transform a feedforward neural network into its integration?

Comment: You mean $M'$ *approximates* $F$, right? The answer to your question might be Yes, as you can always train  a new network to learn $F$. I guess you are looking for a direct non-learning transformation of the weights?

Comment: That's exactly the point. In my real world application the time is limited so that I cannot afford to retrain $F$ for all $M$'s.